# How to put a recyclerview view on top even if the view is the last element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app that has a recyclerview, where a view needs to be at the top depending on the current time. I did a lot of research on how to leave a view at the top, however, the solution found (scrollToPositionWithOffset) just leaves that view visible, and not necessarily at the top. I need this view to always be at the top, even when the number of views is less than the height of the recyclerview or the top view is the last (with views prior to it). In such cases, the previous views would be visible only if scrolled up.
For example:

[image: Click here]

As can be seen, each view is ordered by time, so I can't just insert a view in the first position. In addition, there are times when the visible part of the recyclerview will be smaller than its size, even if there are items before the top view, so the scroll methods do not work here, since they only scroll until the view is visible, and not until it gets to the top. I am implementing this list with Recyclerview and LinearLayoutManager

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make a specific element first in the list under some specified condition? We will be able to help you more easily if you can provide some samples of the code as it currently stands and if you can show us what is happening.

Comment: @RedBassett I edited the post to make it clearer.